# How can I hide the filter icon in Ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to remove the filter icon in ag-grid **whilst keeping the filtering box**

Right now I'm trying to use pure css to hide the icon which in webpack just adds the `aria-hidden="true"`

**CSS I've tried**

```
* /deep/ div.ag-floating-filter-button{
    display:none !important;   
}
```

**Trying to remove this icon**

[image: Icon]

I either want to completely remove the grid icon using `columnsAPI` or find a way with CSS to disable the icon truely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/) describes how to change the icons. I suggest that you change them to an empty string, either in the `gridOptions` or in a css file. here is the gridOptions way with a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview):

```
<ag-grid-angular
    ...
    [icons]="icons"
    ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>


this.icons = {
  filter: ' '
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Use **floatingFilter** and  check **floatingFilterComponentParams**. You can hide the filter button by adding this in columnDefs in gridOptions like below

```
gridOptions = {
  floatingFilter: true
  columnDefs:[{
    ...
    suppressMenu: true,
    floatingFilterComponentParams: {suppressFilterButton:true}
    ...
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside of your 'columnDef' array, you should add floatingFilterComponentParams: {suppressFilterButton: true}. Also if you want to remove menu button at top of your column, you can simply create an 'icons' array and bind it to the ag-grid as an option.

What i mean:

```
columnDef: [
    ...
    floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true }
]
```

and to remove icons:

```
icons = {
    menu: ' ',
    filter: ' ' //optional, we have already disabled it above.
}
```

then

```
<ag-grid-angular
    ...
    [icons]="icons",
    [floatingFilter]="true">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: This actually answers the OP's question specifically - the actual marked answer is a bit of a convoluted way to remove the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can deactivate the filter icon by two ways.

1.) First way: global dactivation

Add `enableFilter: false` to you `gridoptions`.

```
gridOptions = {
  // turn off filtering
  enableFilter: true,
  ...
  columnDefs: [
    ...    
  ]
}
```

2.) Second way: disable per column

Add `suppressFilter: true` to column definition to turn off filter for this column.

```
gridOptions = {
    // turn on filtering
    enableFilter: true,
    ...
    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", filter: "agTextColumnFilter"}, // text filter
        {headerName: "Age",     field: "age",     filter: "agNumberColumnFilter"}, // number filter
        {headerName: "Sport",   field: "sport",   suppressFilter: true} // NO filter
    ]
}
```

For more information read official [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/).

Comment: I want the text box filter, I don't want that little funnel icon to exist at all on the page

Comment: It would be really nice if you can remove your comment  
`// turn off filtering` or change `enableFilter: false` from your first way of implementation. Such misleading it is.
Also this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the filter icon on a particular column, add:

```
menuTabs: []
```

to the column definition.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following css worked:

```
.ag-icon-filter {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the below two properties to disable icons

> suppressMenu: true,
> floatingFilterComponentParams: {
> suppressFilterButton: true }

```
const defaultColDef = {
        sortable: true,
        editable: false,
        flex: 1,
        filter: true,
        floatingFilter: true,
        suppressMenu: true,
        floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true },
    };

 <AgGridReact
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      rowData={rowData}
      defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
 ></AgGridReact>
```

Answer (score -3):

columnDefs: [ {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", filter: "agTextColumnFilter",floatingFilterComponentParams: {suppressFilterButton:true}}]

Comment: You don't even close your first bracket, besides it's better to explain a bit instead of just a line of code.